# Django errors when making migrations after renaming apps

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project and I am encountering errors in the architecture.

I am trying to setup the models in its own package. However, my application keeps giving me errors.

Everything worked until I moved the models into their own package and made a file for each class.

Now whenever I try to run `makemigrations`, I get this error:

```
 ValueError: Unhandled pending operations for models:
  model.state (referred to by fields: testadmin.Member.state, testadmin.Organization.state)
```

I added the models app into the migration command and it somewhat worked -- `python ./manage.py makemigrations models`. However, now I have this new error. For some reason migrations is not recognizing the `State` model.

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues: ERRORS:
models.Member.state: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'State', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
models.Organization.state: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'State', which is either not installed, or is abstract
```

Comment: How did you move the models (and the migrations) exactly? You know: the name of the tables created by Django are in the format "app_model". If you changed the app name, then the table names that Django expects have changed too.

Comment: By the way: a full traceback is not always useful, but posting it doesn't hurt either ;)

Comment: Could you please add your `models.py` code for us to look at? It could easily be a broken relationship causing this error.

Comment: @SoFLy I have put all the models in their own file in a directory

Comment: Django is particular about naming and structure. If you have moved all your models into a models directory things are not going to work. Models need to live in someapp/models.py not anywhere else.

Answer (score 5):

You have renamed your apps without renaming your tables.

Django constructs the table name for your models as `<app-name>_<model-name>`. By changing the name of the apps, you have changed the table name. Django is now looking for tables that do not exist. It's also complaining about migrations, because applied migrations are recorded in the database and they hold a reference to the app name.

You should [create a migration manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemigrations--empty) to take care of these changes:

1. Renaming of tables. You can use [`AlterModelTable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#altermodeltable) for that.

   ```
   class Migration(migrations.Migration):
       # ...
       operations = [
           AlterModelTable('<old-app-name>_modelname', '<new-app-name>_modelname'),
           # ...
       ]
   ```
2. Renaming of migrations. You have to use the [`MigrationRecorder.Migration`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a0ce4c09ff516af52718885120c2231404515428/django/db/migrations/recorder.py#L26) model for that.

   ```
   def rename_migrations_forwards(apps, schema_editor):
       MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(app='<old-app-name>').update(app='<new-app-name>')

   def rename_migrations_reverse(apps, schema_editor):
       MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(app='<new-app-name>').update(app='<old-app-name>')

   class Migration(migrations.Migration):
       # ...
       operations = [
           # ...
           migrations.RunPython(
               rename_migrations_forwards,
               rename_migrations_reverse,
           ),
       ]
   ```

You can skip the renaming of tables if you override [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#db-table) in your model meta. You can't skip the renaming of migrations however.

Comment: I changed my database table names in the code with the meta function.  The issue is something to do with it thinks State has been deleted or something.  I'm not sure -  Does the db track the migrations also? could it be stored int hat?

Comment: @JeremyLewallen: I don't know what "State" is, however yes: migrations are tracked in the db (that's how Django knows if they already run)

Comment: @JeremyLewallen: those `Field defines a relation with model ...` errors are about related fields (many to many). `AlterModelTable` will take care of them